# Word 2007 Template Lines Printing in Document

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007, templates

From Avery.com, I downloaded a template for a 3265 Half-fold greeting card (8.5x11 folded in half). Using Word 2007, I built the card (graphics & text). However, when I print it there are light lines printing down the center and about an inch from the bottom. They are not part of my design I assume they are guidelines built into the template. They do not show on the screen, yet they print. How do I stop them from printing?

Here's a scan of how the printed page looks:

[image: Scan of printed page]

The arrows indicate where the line is printing. It hardly shows on the scan. There is also a white line (absence of color) printing through the fireplace graphic... the graphic does not have this line in it]

Comment: Can you please scan your printed document and post the picture here?

Comment: Done. I could only figure out how to add the scan to my original post.

Comment: Does your print preview show these lines?

Comment: No... they do not show on screen or in the print preview.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your printer then. If you can, try printing the document from a different printer and see if you still see the lines.